# xamp server to wamp server error

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, wampserver

I changed a php project from XAMP to WAMP. when i try to test the forms in project i get an error.

The error is like this

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\widephp\includes\functions\general_functions.php on line 135

and the 135th line is

```
if(!ereg("^[a-z0-9_.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z.]{2,15})",trim($v))) {
```

the full part the line contains given below

```
foreach($fieldEmail as $v) {
    if(!ereg("^[a-z0-9_.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z.]{2,15})",trim($v))) {
        $alert = "Enter a valid Email address";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: At first try to restart all services and tell us your php version.

Answer (score 0):

As the message indicates, the function [`ereg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) is deprecated.

Your platform change most likely included either an upgrade in the php version, or changes in th error output, or maybe both.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php):

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
>   feature is highly discouraged.

My advice: Follow the manuals advice. Use [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead. Keep in mind you have to adjust the syntax of your regex, [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) is the documentation of it in the php manual.

Comment: i changed as u said bt nw email field is not validating am getting  "Enter a valid Email address" this error

Comment: As I've pointed out, you have to adjust the syntax of your regex. If you just want to validate an email, there are better solutions out there if you want to do it properly. Just have a look at this SO post for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade your PHP version (which is not appreciated) or follow the @Bjoern's answer. To downgrade PHP version on wamp:

> WAMP > PHP> Version > Get more

download version under 5.3, install it and than change version:

> WAMP > PHP> Version > 5.2.X

*my edit was declined by @Bjoern, so i write this as an answer.*

Comment: Sorry for declining, but downgrading php shouldn't be the solution here! ;-)